# virt-manager - ImportError: No module named ordered_dict

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, kvm, ikvm

I have KVM server, it has python2.7 version. Now along with python2.7, python3 have been installed. Now if I try to do `virt-manager` I am getting the following error:

```
from .packages.urllib3.packages.ordered_dict import ordered_dict
ImportError: No module named ordered_dict
```

If I remove python3, will it effect any other 2.7 packages/libraries ? .

Answer (score 7):

You need to install urllib3==1.22, later versions not working with requests.

Comment: Using `pip unstill urllib3 && pip install urllib3==1.22` worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, Ubuntu Xenial, with

```
sudo pip uninstall urllib3
```

virt-manager worked again

Answer (score -1):

Please follow below steps to resolve the issue.

```
sudo pip uninstall requests
sudo pip uninstall urllib3
sudo pip install requests
```

Comment: Actually, this worked great for me. Ugly functional workaround >>> non-working state...